# WorkflowRuntime Execution

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I designed a  Workflow in WF4  in visual studio . It is so simple and  I only want to execute this in this way.

```
 using (WorkflowRuntime workflowRuntime = new WorkflowRuntime())
 {
     System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowInstance instance =  workflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(Workflow1));//My workflow
     instance.Start();     
 }
```

But when i execute this i get the following error.

```
The input workflow type must be an Activity.Parameter name: workflowType
```

Comment: What type is Workflow1? Can you post its declaration?

Comment: It is in the Activity libery project   and i am u8sing WPF project To Execute it

Comment: Is this a .NET 3 Activity project or a .NET 4 Activity project? Also note that WorkflowRuntime is a .NET 3 class which became obsolete in .NET 4.5. .NET provides other methods to host/run a workflow, ie WorkflowInvoker, WorkflowApplication and WorkflowServiceHost. Check [Using WorkflowInvoker and WorkflowApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560894(v=vs.100).aspx) for ways to run a workflow in .NET 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar discussion in [Technet](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/e37b3359-5271-4366-ac3b-455d7749be94). The WorkflowRuntime class is part of Workflow Foundation 3 and doesn't work with WF4 types. It is included only for backwards compatibility. In fact, in 4.5 WorkflowRuntime is marked obsolete.

You are probably trying to use a System.Activities.Activity based workflow to WorkflowRuntime, which will raise the ArgumentException error you describe.

To host/run a WF4 workflow you should use one of the following classes: WorkflowInvoker, WorkflowApplication and WorkflowServiceHost. This is described in the documentation, in [Using WorkflowInvoker and WorkflowApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The simplest way is to use WorkflowInvoker to run a workflow as a method, eg:

```
Activity wf = new WriteLine
{
    Text = "Hello World."
};

WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(wf);
```

although this doesn't give you much control over the workflow's lifecycle.

[WorkflowApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) gives you full control and [WorkflowServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activities.workflowservicehost%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) allows you to host the workflow as a WCF service.

In fact, you can host a WF4 workflow using Windows Server AppFabric without creating your own host and let AppFabric manage instances, security and recovery.